# how to do batch insert using R package odbc function dbWriteTable()

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

I have been using dbWriteTable() to save dataframes in R into sql server database for a while.
Normally, I do as following:

```
library(odbc)
con = odbc::dbConnect(odbc(), 
                        Driver = "SQL Server", 
                        Server = server, 
                        Database = "research",
                        Trusted_Connection = "True")
  table = Id(schema = "schemaName", table = "tableName")
  savingResult <- dbWriteTable(con, table, dataframeToSave,append=TRUE,overwrite = FALSE,batch_rows=nrow(dataframeToSave))
```

It works well until recently I am using the same code to save data into a view in the database. This view has a trigger with it. So when you do insert into this view. The trigger will do some checks and save the data into corresponding tables. Basically, I can treat this view as a table.

When I am doing so, my data team staff told me I am not doing a batch insert. I am inserting the data row by row. So if I am inserting a dataframe with 1000 rows, the trigger has been triggered 1000 times. It causes the saving process become very slow.

I thought dbWriteTable() is doing the batch insert all the time. I read from the internet, lost of posts also mentioning that dbWriteTable() is doing the batch insert. My data team staff asked me if this function has a parameter sth similar to FIRE_TRIGGERS. If so, it may solve the issue. However, it seems dbWriteTable() does not have any parameters similar to this one. Does anyone can confirm with if dbWriteTable() is doing a batch insert? If not, is there a way to do the batch insert?

Now I am working around this issue by using dbWriteTable() to write data into a temp table first, then insert the data from the temp table. In this way, the trigger will be only triggered once and the inserting speed is very fast.But I still want to know if there is an easier way to do this without using a temp table.

Thank you.